# What is the alternative for JmsInvokerServiceExporter in Spring 6?

Tags: spring-remoting

We are migrating from Spring boot 2 to Spring boot 3.
Spring boot uses Spring 6 and the support for **org.springframework.jms.remoting.JmsInvokerServiceExporter** is stopped from Spring 6 onwards.

We are currently using **JmsInvokerServiceExporter** to achieve the remoting using spring jms.
What are the best alternatives for remoting using jms?

Thanks in Advance.
Regards
Narayan

I have explored the below alternatives.

1. Move to REST based calls. but this will make both the server and clients to change the code.
2. Java based RMI. But this makes the calls synchronous from asynchronous.

Answer (score 1):

They have completely removed the package

[The package remoting does not exist with the latest spring release 6.0 for JMS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrLSQ.png)

Consider using spring-jms-6.0 jar .It has got all the methods for sending and receiving the message in async .

Need to refactor your existing code to accommodate this .